# Sending ^Z to a process on a Xen Console?

Tags: linux, xen, console, job-control

I have a [Xen](http://www.xen.org/) server with some VMs on it. I'm using `xm console` to view it and run some programmes. However I wanted to put the process in the background, and pressed ^Z (control Z) by habit, but that just put the `xm console` command into the background. Is it possible to send the ^Z to the programme in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would fix the issue?  http://lists.xensource.com/archives/html/xen-users/2006-10/msg00032.html